# Swift Invalid passphrase when connecting to SSID

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to connect programmatically using NEHotspotConfiguration (see code below). However, when i try to connect, the error says : "invalid WPA/WPA2 passphrase length", but i'm connecting an open network with no password required.

I've seen some solutions but there are a lot of workarounds that i cannot use because of quality purposes.

```
let wifiConfig = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: SSID, passphrase: "", isWEP: false)

    wifiConfig.joinOnce = false

    NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(wifiConfig) { error in

        if let error = error{
            print("Error: " + (error.localizedDescription))
        }else {
            print("Connected.")
        }
    }
```

What could i do to fix it?

Comment: Assuming this is an "open" network, there seems to be a different API. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration

Comment: Yep, you're right! Thank you!

Comment: I guess I could have made this into an Answer... <lazy>

Comment: Yep, at least you get a score xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific API for open networks. Looking at the [API docs for NEHotspotConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration) it looks like you should be using `init(ssid: String)` instead of `init(ssid: String, passphrase: String, isWEP: Bool)`

Comment: Hi, I am using Open network API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration/2866713-initwithssid?language=objc) but in objective C and still getting same error. Is it a bug in object C api?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe research this further and if you don't find a solution then raise a new question with  all the details as outlined in [ask].